# Facebook Get Status message from node C# Facebook SDK

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-c#-sdk

I am trying to retrieve a message from a node (my own status message):
I am using C# Facebook SDK. My GET request is the following:

`status = fb.Get("/v2.2/100006927xxxxxx_1568238173xxxxxx?fields=message")`

I tested this in Graph Explorer on the development site and it works.

but in my application I get an "Unsuppported Get Request #100" error.

Is there something new because I think that worked before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the access token you are using on Graph API Explorer matches the one you are using in your application.

[image: Dropdown menu]

In Graph API Explorer check three calls

- `/app` to see which app you are using
- `/me/permissions` to see what permission is granted in the application
- `/me` to see which app scoped user ID has been assigned

Depending on the access token and the application, the privacy level of that status might not be able available to you.

e.g. `100006927xxxxxx` looks like an app scoped user ID

This will mean that only one particular application will be able to access this resource.

Comment: Thanks, phwd i had the user_status not in my extended permissions :(